# How to attach onDragStart to Draggable in react-beautiful-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

In the [docs](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/draggable.md#draghandleprops-type-information) it says:

> `DragHandleProps` need to be applied to the node that you want to be the drag handle. This is a number of props that need to be applied to the `<Draggable />` node. The simplest approach is to spread the props onto the draggable node (`{...provided.dragHandleProps}`). However, you are also welcome to monkey patch these props if you also need to respond to them. `DragHandleProps` will be `null` when `isDragDisabled` is set to true.
>
> `dragHandleProps` Type information

```
type DragHandleProps = {|
  // what draggable the handle belongs to
  'data-rbd-drag-handle-draggable-id': DraggableId,

  // What DragDropContext the drag handle is in
  'data-rbd-drag-handle-context-id': ContextId,

  // Id of hidden element that contains the lift instruction (nicer screen reader text)
  'aria-labelledby': ElementId,

  // Allow tabbing to this element
  tabIndex: number,

  // Stop html5 drag and drop
  draggable: boolean,
  onDragStart: (event: DragEvent) => void,
|};
```

I want to attach `onDragStart` to the `Draggable` so that it is fired only when a particular set of elements is dragged (as opposed to attaching it to `DragDropContext`).
Using the example from the docs I do:

```
<Draggable draggableId="draggable-1" index={0}>
  {(provided, snapshot) => (
    <div
      ref={provided.innerRef}
      {...provided.draggableProps}
      {...provided.dragHandleProps}
      onDragStart={() => console.log('onDragStart')}
    >
      Drag me!
    </div>
  )}
</Draggable>
```

however it doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas how to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

It can only be used only in DragDropContext for the Draggable element.

```
<DragDropContext
         onDragStart={()=>{alert('onDragStart')}}
         onDragEnd={()=>{alert('onDragEnd')}}>
</DragDropContext>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onDragStart` and `onDragEnd` are events for `DragDropContext` component only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this kind of behavior, you can wrap the `react-beautiful-dnd` context provider with your context provider, then use a hook to register the events you want in every component.

Context Provider - needs to wrap the app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  DragDropContext
} from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

export const MyDragDropContext = React.createContext({});

export const DragAndDropContext = ({
  children
}) => {
  const [eventsMap] = React.useState(() => new Map());

  const addEvent = (event, callback) => {
    eventsMap.set(event, callback);
  };

  const emitEvent = (event, ...rest) => {
    if (!eventsMap.has(event)) return;
    eventsMap.get(event)(...rest);
  };

  const removeEvent = (event) => {
    eventsMap.delete(event);
  };

  const handleDragEnd = (item) => {
    if (!item.destination) return;
    emitEvent(item.destination.droppableId, {
      action: 'DRAG_END',
      item
    });
  };

  const handleDragStart = (item) => {
    if (!item.source) return;
    emitEvent(item.source.droppableId, {
      action: 'DRAG_START',
      item
    });
  };

  return ( <
    MyDragDropContext.Provider value = {{addEvent,removeEvent}} >
      <DragDropContext 
        onDragStart = {handleDragStart}
        onDragEnd = {handleDragEnd} 
      > 
        {children} 
      </DragDropContext> 
    </MyDragDropContext.Provider >
  );
};
```

Hook:

```js
import React, {
  useRef
} from 'react';
import {
  MyDragDropContext
} from './DragAndDropContext';

export interface DragMonitorListener {
  onDragStart(item) : void;
  onDragEnd(item) : void;
}

export default function useDragMonitor(droppableId, listener: DragMonitorListener) {
  const {
    addEvent,
    removeEvent
  } = React.useContext < any > (MyDragDropContext);
  const savedListener = useRef < DragMonitorListener > ();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    savedListener.current = listener;
    addEvent(droppableId, ({
      action,
      item
    }) => {
      if (action === 'DRAG_START') {
        listener.onDragStart(item);
      } else if (action === 'DRAG_END') {
        listener.onDragEnd(item);
      }
    });
    return () => removeEvent(droppableId);
  }, []);
}
```

To get the callbacks in your component you need to register with the droppable id:

```js
useDragMonitor('droppable-id', {
  onDragStart(item) {
    console.log('onDragStart', item);
  },
  onDragEnd(item) {
    console.log('onDragEnd', item);
  },
});
```